# function symmetric around a point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, logarithms

I need some quick help solving this:

What is y(ln(2))if the function y satisfies
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=1-y^2$$

and is symmetric about the point (ln(4),0)?

I know that a function is symmetric about the point (ln(4),0) if the function f defined by

$$f(x)=y(x+ln(4))$$ is odd, meaning

$$f(-x)=-f(x)\forall x)$$
From formulas in my textbook, but I don't understand how to apply it correctly.

Comment: Do you know how to solve $y'=1-y^2?$

Answer (score 2):

The general solution to the differential equation is
$$y(x)=\tanh(x-x_0) $$ where $x_0$ is a constant to be determined. Since $\tanh$ is symmetric (odd) around $0$, you should choose $x_0=\ln4$. It is then easy to see that $$y(\ln2)=\tanh(\ln2-\ln4)=\tanh \left(\ln \frac{1}{2} \right)=-\frac{3}{5}. $$